# How do I change the angle of a cv2 rectangle?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am using a cv2 rectangle for bounding box purposes and I want to rotate it about its axis by some angle. Since the warpAffine function is used to rotate images, I am unable to use it here.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in function to do this in `cv2`. You can get around this by determining the coordinates of the four corners of your rotated rectangle, the using `cv2.polylines` to plot it.

Here's a function that does exactly so, and can be used as a drop-in replacememt for `cv2.rectangle` - the only additional argumenty is `rotation` (which should be in degrees):

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos, sin

def rotated_rectangle(image, start_point, end_point, color, thickness, rotation=0):
    center_point = [(start_point[0]+end_point[0])//2, (start_point[1]+end_point[1])//2]
    height = end_point[1] - start_point[1]
    width = end_point[0] - start_point[0]
    angle = np.radians(rotation)
    
    # Determine the coordinates of the 4 corner points
    rotated_rect_points = []
    x = center_point[0] + ((width / 2) * cos(angle)) - ((height / 2) * sin(angle))
    y = center_point[1] + ((width / 2) * sin(angle)) + ((height / 2) * cos(angle))
    rotated_rect_points.append([x,y])
    x = center_point[0] - ((width / 2) * cos(angle)) - ((height / 2) * sin(angle))
    y = center_point[1] - ((width / 2) * sin(angle)) + ((height / 2) * cos(angle))
    rotated_rect_points.append([x,y])
    x = center_point[0] - ((width / 2) * cos(angle)) + ((height / 2) * sin(angle))
    y = center_point[1]- ((width / 2) * sin(angle)) - ((height / 2) * cos(angle))
    rotated_rect_points.append([x,y])
    x = center_point[0] + ((width / 2) * cos(angle)) + ((height / 2) * sin(angle))
    y = center_point[1] + ((width / 2) * sin(angle)) - ((height / 2) * cos(angle))
    rotated_rect_points.append([x,y])
    cv2.polylines(image, np.array([rotated_rect_points], np.int32), True, color, thickness)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already some time I used it, but as far as I remember, all these ROI types are just plain x-y rectangles. No rotation is possible (you can also see from the constructors, there is no way how to define the rotation). So it is always wide along x-axis and high along y-axis.

If you want to just draw rectangle, I propose to just determine all four corner points and then by simple lines draw the bounding box. Eventually you can use polylines to do it in one command.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to apply an affine transformation to points instead of a whole image, you can use [`cv.transform`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga393164aa54bb9169ce0a8cc44e08ff22). [`cv.getRotationMatrix2D`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gafbbc470ce83812914a70abfb604f4326) gets you an affine transformation to rotate your rectangle points around any arbitrary center.

OpenCV has the notion of a `RotatedRect`. You can trivially construct them given width, height, and an angle. You don't need to know any trigonometry and you need no calculations at all.

[`RotatedRect::points()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dd6/classcv_1_1RotatedRect.html#a69d648b086f26dbce0029facae9bfb2d) gives you the corners of the rectangle. You can use those to draw the rectangle as a polygon or "contour".

The equivalent in Python is the [`cv.boxPoints`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf78d467e024b4d7936cf9397185d2f5c) function. It takes the python tuple of numbers that represents the RotatedRect C++ structure.

The documentation for these functions/methods also refers to a [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/d62/tutorial_bounding_rotated_ellipses.html) that is included in OpenCV documentation. It uses `drawContours` and passes the four corner points as one contour.